# Topology on Stone Spaces of Boolean Algebra

Tags: general-topology, logic, boolean-algebra

What are the open sets of a Stone space of a Boolean algebra B?
[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_space), they are the ultrafilters on B that contain an element of B.  However, this cannot be the case since an ultrafilter is a set of subsets of B and contains no elements of B.  Using the alternate definition of the Stone space as the space of homomorphisms from B to {0,1} doesn't offer much help, either.

Comment: An ultrafilter on a Boolean algebra is a subset of $B$, not of the power set of $B$. You may be confused because $B$ itself may be viewed as (part of) a power set of of another set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confused by the two meanings of ultrafilter. In the context of a Boolean algebra $B$, an ultrafilter is just a maximal proper filter, that is, a subset of $B$ that is closed under $\wedge$, upward closed, and does not contain $0$. The Stone space $M(B)$ consists of all such maximal filters, and its usual topology is generated by basic open sets of the form
$$
N_p = \{ f \in M(B) : p \in f \}
$$
with one such basic open set $N_p$ for each $p \in B$.

There is a second, incompatible meaning of ultrafilter: an ultrafilter on an arbitrary set $S$ is a maximal filter in the above sense on the lattice of subsets of $S$. This is what people mean when they say "an ultrafilter on $\omega$", for example.  When $S$ is already being treated as a lattice, the former sense is usually what is meant, but you can only tell by context.